# Combining two tables different criteria

Tags: php, mysql, sql

basically im just trying to finish off a project im working on, having a little trouble finding the right syntax to use for this SQL statement.

Basically what i have two different tables:

```
Customer:
companyid
companyname
etc etc.

Machine:
machineid
model
serial
companyid
```

Now usually this would be easy as i would just join the companyid, however, i need to do this slightly differently this time. I need to return specific data from the tables of customer using the customers id to search, and specific data from the tables of machine, using the machine id to search.

Im pretty tired so i do apologise if the answer is staring me straight in the face, but heres what i was working on, again i know its more than likely wrong so i am sorry i have tried searching but to no avail:

```
$customerquery = mysql_query("
            SELECT customer.companyid, customer.companyname, 
                   customer.companyaddress, customer.postcode, 
                   customer.telephone, customer.mobile, 
                   machine.machineid, machine.model, 
                   machine.serial 
            FROM customer, machine 
            WHERE customer.companyid=$customerid AND 
                  machine.machineid=$machineid
            ");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, 
Thankyou!

Comment: You're missing the joining clause `WHERE customer.companyid = machine.companyid`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query produces cartesian product since you miss the condition on where the tables should be joined. This is an old syntax of join (`SQL-89`)

```
SELECT customer.companyid, customer.companyname, 
       customer.companyaddress, customer.postcode, 
       customer.telephone, customer.mobile, 
       machine.machineid, machine.model, 
       machine.serial 
FROM   customer, machine 
WHERE  customer.companyid = $customerid AND 
       machine.machineid = $machineid AND
       customer.companyid = machine.companyid -- you missed this one producing
                                              -- cartesian product
```

New syntax of join (`SQL-92`)

```
SELECT customer.companyid, customer.companyname, 
       customer.companyaddress, customer.postcode, 
       customer.telephone, customer.mobile, 
       machine.machineid, machine.model, 
       machine.serial 
FROM   customer INNER JOIN machine 
          ON customer.companyid = machine.companyid 
WHERE  customer.companyid = $customerid AND 
       machine.machineid = $machineid
```

Comment: John, you are a lifesaver sir. Im sorry to ask such a silly question, no sleep makes life much harder. Thankyou again, you have saved me alot of headaches!

Comment: trained yourself to use `ANSI SQL-92` syntax when joining tables. old syntax of `INNER JOIN` is prone to error because if you missed the condition, it will not generate an error message but will likely do cartesian product of the results. in new version, you are obliged to specify the condition in `ON` clause. :) you are welcome.

Comment: Another quick question for you john, just your opinion. Once i retrieve the selected data, im going to be using it to post into a different database table along with some other data inputted via the user. Would the best way to do this as i was thinking be to take the data returned via the result, place this into hidden input boxes in the form being used for the data inputted via the user, or is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: you can do that cleanly through sql. try search `INSERT...SELECT` statement. [**INSERT...SELECT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)